# Значения переменных a, b, c поменять местами так, чтобы a>b>c

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(0,"");
    int a,b,c;
    cout<<"Введите значение а "<<endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Введите значение b " << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Введите значение c " << endl;
    cin >> c;

    if (a > b && a > c && b > c) {
        cout<<"a > b > c"<<endl;
    }
    else {
        cout<<"а должне быть больше b, с и b должно быть больше с"<<endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А какой текст ошибки?

Comment: как сделать,чтобы поменять их местами

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно 3-х сравнений (и максимум 3-х обменов).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  if (ac != 4)
    exit((puts("Usage: ./a.out a-num b-num c-num"), 1));
  int a = atoi(av[1]), b = atoi(av[2]), c = atoi(av[3]);

#define SWAP(x, y) ({int _t = x; x = y; y = _t;})  
  if (a < b)
    SWAP(a, b);
  if (a < c)
    SWAP(a, c);
  if (b < c)
    SWAP(b, c);

  return printf("a: %d   b: %d   c: %d\n", a, b, c) < 0;
}
```

Comment: согласен, но вряд ли ТС разберется в этом, я постарался более понятно для него расписать

Comment: @Lolidze, пусть сразу учится...

Comment: это тоже самое, что дать школьнику книгу по матану, вероятность, что он разберется есть, но она мала. Тут лучше с легкого начинать, имхо

Answer (score 1):

Максимально упростил код, что бы вы поняли :

```
else {

        int sr=b;
        int max = b; 
        int min =b;

if(a > b) //находим макс значение
    max = a;
if(max < c)
    max = c;

if(a < b) //находим мин значение
   min = a;
if(min > c)
      min = c;

if (b > min && b<max) //находим среднее значение
sr = b;
if (a > min && a<max)
sr = a;
if (c > min && c<max)
sr = c;

//переприсваеваем значения для переменных, что бы a>b>c
   a =max; 
   b = sr;
   c = min;


        cout<<a<<b<<c<<endl; //выводим 
    }
```